# Cannot convert C++ type to QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtcore, qt-signals

I am trying to pass QList with custom elements to QML via signal. But in qml I got QVariant(QList) element instead of common javascript array. There is my code:

```
class reader : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QList<bashQuote*> data READ getData WRITE setData NOTIFY dataChanged)

public:
    explicit reader(QObject *parent = 0);
    Q_INVOKABLE void download(const QString& str);
    QList<bashQuote*> getData() const { return data;}

signals:
    void dataChanged(QList<bashQuote*> argum);

public slots:
    void setData(QList<bashQuote*> arg);
public:

    QList<bashQuote*> data;
};


class bashQuote : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit bashQuote(QObject *parent = 0);
    QString quote;
signals:

public slots:

};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(bashQuote*)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    qmlRegisterType<reader>("com.lobster.reader", 1, 0, "Reader");
    qRegisterMetaType<bashQuote*>("BashQuotePtr");

    return SailfishApp::main(argc, argv);
}
```

qml file:

```
Page {
    id: page

    Reader {
        id: bestReader
        onDataChanged: {
            console.log("!!!!!!!!!!!!!onDataChanged")
        }
    }

    // To enable PullDownMenu, place our content in a SilicaFlickable
    SilicaFlickable {
        anchors.fill: parent

        Column {
            id: column

            Connections {
                 target: bestReader
                 onDataChanged: {
                     console.log(argum)
                     console.log(argum[0])
                 }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

console output is:

```
[D] onDataChanged:41 - !!!!!!!!!!!!!onDataChanged
[D] onDataChanged:70 - QVariant(QList<bashQuote*>)
[D] onDataChanged:71 - undefined
```

However when I changed BashQuote to int everything worked

Answer (score 0):

If a read-only property is enough for you and bashQuote inherits QObject, then you need to this with QtQuick 2 below. You could look into [QQmlListProperty](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qqmllistproperty.html) or `QDeclarativeListProperty` with QtQuick1:

```
Q_PROPERTY(QQmlListProperty<bashQuote*> data READ getData
           WRITE setData NOTIFY dataChanged);
```

Otherwise, I would just try to register your bashQuote type with the QMetaObject system and QVariantList.

Comment: thx for you answer, but how to register bashQuote with QMetaObject system? I found qRegisterMetaType function and Q_DECLARE_METATYPE macros in the internet, but it look like as doesn't work :(

Comment: @Lobster: [Does not work](http://www.macieira.org/blog/2012/05/doesnt-work-doesnt-work/) does not work.

Comment: I changed void setData(QList<bashQuote*> arg); signal to void reader::setData(QVariantList arg) and add elements to that list like that:
    bashQuote b;
    b.quote = "two";
    QVariantList dat;
    dat.push_back(QVariant::fromValue(b));
After that in QML I got array of QVariant(bashQuote) elements, but I cannot access to any properties and functions of that object

Comment: Did you resolve this, Lobster? Otherwise, I will just delete my answer, I think. It seems `QQmlListProperty` only supports read-only properties at this point of time.